# AccountAuthenticatorActivity for AppCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity, android-authenticator

I'm making an authenticator following the tutorial: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

The login Activity requires to extend `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, the issue starts here: `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` extends the regular `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity`.

Using the regular `Activity` in AppCompat results in a `Activity` without `ActionBar`. I want to use `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` AND having an `ActionBar`.

Comment: [use AppCompatDelegate](https://github.com/SelvinPL/SyncFrameworkAndroid/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/pl/selvin/android/listsyncsample/authenticator/AccountAuthenticatorActivityAppCompat.java) you can simply derive your activity from this implementation and then use `getDelegate().setSupportActionBar()`

Comment: link to Android docs for AppCompatDelegate (v7 support library) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is `AppCompatDelegate`, my code is based on the `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` class generated by Android Studio:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AppCompatAuthActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }

}
```

The `AppCompatDelegate` is the key to add `ActionBar` to ANY regular `Activity` (for example `PreferenceActivity`).

Don't forget your activity must extend `AppCompatAuthActivity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer can be applied to `PreferenceActivity` and other `Activity` classes that extends the regular `Activity` class.

Comment: Oh my god, please copy paste that code exactly as is. I didn't copy it exactly, I invoked `super.onCreate()` before `getDelegate().onCreate()` and it resulted in bug that caused `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to not get called at all even after calling `setSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 13):

I think that is not the real solution. If you are doing an app with support libraries, mixing AppCompatActivities, Fragments &c with the standard ones is not a good idea.

I´ve created an `AccountAuthenticatorAppCompatActivity` extending `AppCompatActivity` and then copy/paste the code from API `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` and it seems to work properly.

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AccountAuthenticatorResponse mAccountAuthenticatorResponse = null;
    private Bundle mResultBundle = null;

    public final void setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle result) {
        mResultBundle = result;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        mAccountAuthenticatorResponse =
                getIntent().getParcelableExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE);

        if (mAccountAuthenticatorResponse != null) {
            mAccountAuthenticatorResponse.onRequestContinued();
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        if (mAccountAuthenticatorResponse != null) {
            // send the result bundle back if set, otherwise send an error.
            if (mResultBundle != null) {
                mAccountAuthenticatorResponse.onResult(mResultBundle);
            } else {
                mAccountAuthenticatorResponse.onError(AccountManager.ERROR_CODE_CANCELED,
                        "canceled");
            }
            mAccountAuthenticatorResponse = null;
        }
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: I'm with @marcRDZ.  That delegate solution is *way* overly complicated.  The code for the AccountAuthenticatorActivity is dead simple (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.java) . Just duplicate it in your AppCompatActivity!

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike thank you man
i was looking for this only u should have posted this as answer ;)

Comment: @marcRDZ u should have shown some code implementation | just a tip | still ur answer is good | good day